# Heroku Application Error After Form Submittal, But No Error Logged?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3

I get an error when I try to create a new form with image uploading to Amazon S3.

[image]

I think its because of my photo uploads, but not too sure. when I do this in my development environment, no issues. I'm using Amazon S3, in development as well.

I checked `heroku logs` and I get no error.

Once I create a new form, it supposed to direct me to that `show.html.erb` page, with the id in the URL (ie: www.example.com/projects/this-is-new-page), but instead, it sent me to `www.example.com/projects` and the error.

Oh, I'm also using `friendly_id gem`

```
def create
  @project = project.new(project_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @project.save

      if params[:photos]
        params[:photos].each { |image|
          @project.project_images.create(photo: image)
        }
      end
      format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Trip was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @project }
  else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

When I go back to www.example.com/projects/this-is-new-page, it works. But I only get this error right after I upload or submit a form.

Comment: it is possible that uploading of images is taking too much time that it time out.. do you see any time out errors i logs.

Comment: @Athar no time out logs, last logged item before the application error was that it says `Redirected to http://www.example.com/projects/this-is-new-page`, but of course it didn't get redirected there, it got sent to `http://www.example.com/projects/` with error. My route is set to `root 'projects#index'`

Comment: i would suggest that you should try with single attachment first with smalles size and see if things are going well or not. is there some coding error or not. it is also possible. if things are only crashing with single small file as well then i guess it is also possible that it is some coding issue.

Comment: @Athar that could be a possibility. I think it is timing out. But I don't see any errors. I'm able to upload smaller photos and stuff. Is there anything I can so it won't timeout? Are there some best practices?

Comment: i think you might need to change your logic abit that first it creates a product with single image, and then for multiple images, you can use https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails to upload multiple images at a time and it provides good interface. or you can somehow add some constrant to not upload files with large side. demo: https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/